# Where can I find the characters of protothetic?

Tags: unicode, char

I work on [Leśniewski's Protothetic](http://www.people.man.ac.uk/~zlsiial/thesis.pdf) (an obscure logic notation) and I need some special charaters.
I already have "⌞ ⌟⌜ ⌝" but I don't know where I can find the others:

[image: List of Characters]

Someone know where can I find them (if they exist)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try drawing it on [shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/). I tried and didn't find it, so maybe it is not in their database. But my drawing is also pretty bad.

Otherwise you could search them on [unicode-table.com](http://unicode-table.com/en/). They should have them if they exist. But it will probably take some time to search through all the characters. Good luck!